# No icon themes displayed. Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, gnome, themes, icons, icon-themes

I deleted duplicate themes in the home/.themes folder and now no applications icons are displayed. I can apply themes and all themes are listed however either no icons or default blank icons are displayed.

I moved all themes to the usr/share/themes, rebooted but still the same issue.

Is there a way to reset icons? or clear cache?

I have tried:

```
gtk-update-icon-cache
```

Thanks

Ubuntu Gnome 3.10 (Ubuntu 14.04)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-gnome-desktop
```